# How to print i after running for loop twice?

Tags: python, for-loop, range, nested-loops

I'm trying to print out the value of `i` every time the inner loop finishes iterating.
`i` can be `10`, `20`, `200`, `2000`, or any number really, but for this instance I chose `100`.

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    for ii in range(1, 100):
        i += 1
    print(i)
print(i + i)
```

Given Output:

```
100
101
```

Wanted Output:

```
100
200
```

How can I get the wanted output?

Comment: How about `for i in range(1, 3): print(i * 100)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your outer loop variable is *also* named `i`. Since you're overloading that variable name, it gets reset every time.

Consider instead using the common idiom `for _ in range(n)` which will execute its contents `n` times.

```py
x = 0
for _ in range(3):
    for _ in range(100):
        x += 1
    print(x)
```

---

although as solid.py rightly points out in the comments on the question, for this specific use case it's probably easier to not add 1 over and over again, and instead just use math or a more appropriate range.

```py
for i in range(1, 3):
    print(i * 100)

# or

for i in range(100, 301, 100):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

First off there is no need for the inner loop to increment by a constant value. This does the same as your code above but in a clearer way:

```py
for i in range(1,3):
    i += 100
    print(i)
print(i+i)
```

This will print

```
101
102
103
```

To get your output, try using an auxiliary variable:

```
x = 0
for _ in range(1, 3):
    x += 100
    print(x)
```

which will get your desired output

Answer (score 1):

The code below works by unpacking all values within the `range()` by using the `*` operator.
**Sidenote:** The `range()` function has a step parameter, that specifies the incrementation.

```
print(*range(100, 300, 100))
```

The simpler version of the code above would be:

```
for i in range(100, 300, 100):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
100 200
```